# Removing underline from MaskedEditValidator for a phone field?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Is it possible to display the mask for a MaskedEditExtender in a TextBox as (without the underlines)

```
(   )   -
```

instead of

```
(   )___-____
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the PromptCharacter attribute is what you are looking for.  Sample taken from the Ajax Control Toolkit homepage, with attribute added.

```
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender
TargetControlID="TextBox2" 
Mask="9,999,999.99"
MessageValidatorTip="true" 
OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" 
OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"
MaskType="Number" 
InputDirection="RightToLeft" 
AcceptNegative="Left" 
DisplayMoney="Left"
ErrorTooltipEnabled="True"
PromptCharacter=" "/>
```

Check [here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/maskededit/maskededit.aspx), expand MaskedEditExtender Properties.

Comment: Hai mathews i want dd/mm/yyyy instead of __/__/____